# Difference- limit,colimit and border

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Please what is the difference and usage of these 3 words:
limit, co-limit and border.
Also a usage of each will be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Border is usually used to signify the boundary between two countries. It could also be the outside edge of something. It could be confused with Boarder,as in to enter a ship or receiving meals and lodgings somewhere.

Limit is the maximum extent of something, the highest, longest, fastest, slowest etc.
it could be high or low depending on context, its about extremes, the opposite is minimum.

Sorry to say I'm not too sure on CO-limit. It's not a term I've heard before, and im confident you don't find it in common English. It could mean CO as in carbon monoxide limit. It could also be a maths term. Maybe it's Co as in company, and its about sharing an agreed limit

The reading was 0.26, dangerously close to the CO-limit.

50 is the limit, you won't get more. * Border doesnt work here*

They marched towards the border. *limit doesnt work here, but ''their limits'' does and changes the meaning entirely in a poetic way*